# shell to find a file , execute it - exit if 'error' and continue if ' no error'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have to write a shell script and i don't know how to go about it.
Basically i have to write a script where i'd find a file ( it could be possibly named differently). If either file exists then it must be executed, if it returns a 0 ( no error), it should continue the build, if it's not equal to 0 ( returns with error), it should exit. If either file is not found it should continue the build.

the file i have to find could be either file.1 or file.2 so it could be either named (file.1), or (file.2).

some of the conditions to make it more clear.
1) if either file  exists , it should execute - if it has any errors it should exit, if no errors it should continue.
2) none could exist, if that's the case then it should continue the build. 
3) both files will not be present at the same time ( additional info)

I have tried to write a script but i doubt it's even closer to what i am looking for.

```
if [-f /home/(file.1) or (file.2)]
then 
  -exec /home/(file.1) or (file.2)
   if [ $! -eq 0]; then
   echo "no errors continuing build"
   fi
   else
   if [ $! -ne 0] ; then
   exit ;
   fi
else 
   echo "/home/(file.1) or (file.2) not found, continuing build"
fi
```

any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you execute an XML file?

Comment: So to clarify, is this right: succeed if and only if EITHER (1) both do not exist, or (2) at least one of them exists and succeeds when run?

Comment: Ray, either file could exit or even none could exit. ( both will not be present at the same time) .                                            1)I want to find the file, it should execute if either exists.2) if it has any errors while executing it should exit, 3) if there are no errors while executing it shouldn't exit , 4) if none file are present it shouldn't exit.

Comment: There are four cases to consider: (1) both files are found, (2) and (3) one of the files is found, and (4) neither file is found.  Your description does not clearly (to my mind) state what to do in cases (1) and (4).  When programming, you really do have to think of all the possibilities like that, and make sure you know what you're going to do in each case.  Also, 'find a file' on Unix often means 'run the `find` command to locate a file'.  It is not entirely clear, but from your sample code, it appears that you know where the two files will be found, if they're found anywhere.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 1) both files will not be present at the same time, 4) if neither files are found it should continue, and not exit out. I hope it's clear

Comment: Exactly *two* lines of your sample script have valid Bash syntax, and neither of them will ever be executed.

Comment: @CodeGnome: I count as many as nine valid lines. Lines 1, 3, 4 and 8 are the only ones with problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DOIT=""
for f in file1.sh file2.sh; do
  if [ -x /home/$f ]; then DOIT="/home/$f"; break; fi
done
if [ -z "$DOIT" ]; then echo "Files not found, continuing build"; fi
if [ -n "$DOIT" ]; then $DOIT && echo "No Errors" || exit 1; fi
```

For those confused about my syntax, try running this:

```
true && echo "is true" || echo "is false"
false && echo "is true" || echo "is false"
```

Comment: Can you explain what this script will do? Thanks

Comment: @user1477324: Line 1: initialize;  Line 2-4: determine the existence of your requested files (the first one found will be used).  Line 5: complain if your requested files do not exist.  Line 6: execute the requested file if it does exist.  Also print "No Errors" if there were no errors.  Also exit if there were errors.

Comment: sorry i am pretty new to shell scripting as you can clearly tell, but will this print errors if there were any? can you explain a bit more about 'initialize', and line '2-4'? this will find the file in home itself?

Comment: +1 - @user1477324: This is not too different from what I'd have written, although I wonder whether what you really need is a `make` file.

Comment: @Dennis, no i don't need to make file. I just want to be able to find  either files if any exists, execute it, exit if any error or continue if no errors. If none exists then it should continue regardleess. I hope i am making sense to you

Comment: @user1477324: Any output that file1 or file2 produce will be printed to standard out, just as if you had said `echo hello world`.  By initialize I mean that it sets DOIT=to the empty string so that any previous value of DOIT will be destroyed.  This is so that if line three does NOT match, then line five will run and line six will not run.  This will find the two scripts in /home/file1.sh and /home/file2.sh. Replace "/home" if they exist somewhere else.  More sophisticated options are available if you lied about where the programs were and how they could be found.

Comment: @user1477324: I mentioned `make` files because you used the phrase "continue the build".

Comment: @DennisWilliamson i mean't continue with the script.

Comment: @SethRobertson, one more question, can i replace 'DOIT' with anything? Thanks much

Comment: @user1477324: DOIT is a variable name.  You can replace it with anything but...it doesn't mean anything either.  It will have the exact same behavior if you call it FOO or AKLJDFKLJ123asdf.  The *contents* of the variable are what matter, and that is what is being assigned in line 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting the line

```
file.sh
```

in your script should work, if you set up your script to exit on errors.

For example, if your script was

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo one
./file.sh
echo two
```

Then if `file.sh` exists and is executable it would run and your whole script would run.  If not, the script would fail when it tried to execute the non-existing file.

If you want to execute one file or the other, extend the idea to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo one
./file1.sh || ./file2.sh
echo two
```

This means if `file1.sh` does not exist, it will try `file2.sh` and if that is there it will run and your whole script will run.

This give preference to `file1` of course, meaning if they both exist, then only file1 will run.

Comment: This doesn't attempt to execute file.xml if file.sh doesn't exist

Comment: I don't know how to execute `file.xml` so I used `file2.sh`.  Oh, actually if you make `file.xml` executable somehow.....  Can you clarify?

Comment: file1||file2 didn't exist when I looked at your answer originally, but this too has a problem.  instead of erroring out if file1 exists but returns an error, it attempts to execute file2 (which could in theory exist and return success).

Comment: Let's just name them file1 and file2 to make it easier.

Comment: Good point, Seth, I misread the question.  I thought the OP wanted to find and execute one or the other and if one failed, execute the other, and if they both failed that would be an error.  The question looked at first like "you must execute one or the other".